# "Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://favicon/"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im trying to load a url's favicon using chromes favicon url:

```
<img class='icon' src='chrome://favicon/yahoo.com' />
```

But im getting the error :

```
"Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://favicon/yahoo.com"
```

And in the manifest i have:

```
  "permissions": [
    "chrome://favicon/"
],
```

There isnt much available online about this topic. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `<img class='icon' src='http://yahoo.com/favicon.ico' />`?

Comment: @A.Rodas Yeah its slower, and if theres no favicon, chrome://favicon returns a default image.

Comment: There is no support for this yet: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=11854

Comment: @JonahKatz: I know it's an old thread. But for those who finds it via Google. Your favicon URL should've been `chrome://favicon/https://www.yahoo.com/` and then it would work with that permissions line. In other words use the protocol part of the URL where you want the favicon from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Problems in your code

- `"permissions": ["chrome://favicon/"]`, is an invalid pattern in manifest file

If you want to use the URL of the tab's `favicon` use chrome.tabs API in extension pages.

## Demonstration

#### manifest.json

Registered background page and added necessary permissions.

```
{
    "name": "Fav Icon",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800881/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-chrome-favicon",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

#### background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({
    "active": true,//fetch active tabs
    "currentWindow": true,//fetch tabs in current window
    "status": "complete",//fetch completely loaded windows
    "windowType": "normal"//fetch normal windows
}, function (tabs) {
    for (tab in tabs) {
        console.log(tabs[tab].favIconUrl);// Use this URL as needed
    }
});
```

chrome.tabs.query will work in extension pages, if you want to use in content scripts use message passing to communicate URL.

## References

- [chrome.tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html)
- [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)

Comment: I'm not sure how old this post is, but `"permissions": ["chrome://favicon/"]` is a perfectly valid manifest file declaration. It is actually needed to display urls as such: `chrome://favicon/http://stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1):

The URL needs to include the scheme as well:

```html
<img src="chrome://favicon/http://www.yahoo.com">
```

Comment: Where are you trying to load this image? It probably will only work in the background page or extension window.

Comment: Im loading it via a popup.js file

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this issue and both

`"permissions": ["chrome://favicon/"]` and `"permissions": ["chrome://favicon/*"]`

worked as expected.

Chrome version 52.0.2743.116

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know it's an old post but for those who are here to find this answer, why it is showing like this is basically because `chrome://favicon/` and `chrome://favicon/*` both should be added in your mainfest.json

```
"permissions": ["chrome://favicon/", "chrome://favicon/*"]
```

*NOTICE: mainfest v3 will have API dedicated to this but for now we don't have much blogs on that and also mainfest v2 will be no longer supported after 2023.*

Answer (score 0):

You can now use **favicon** as the permission with `_favicon/?pageUrl=${url}&size=32` to load icons

[Here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/main/api/favicon/content.js) is an example

Answer (score 0):

Unfurtunely it will not work as it was in manifest v2. You have to use it differently.

#### Method 1 (lazy)

`https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=https://stackoverflow.com/`

#### Method 2 (official)

`manifest.json`

```
  "permissions": [
    "favicon"
  ],
```

```
export const favicon = (pageUrl: string, size: number = 24) => {
  const url = new URL(`chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/_favicon/`);
  url.searchParams.append("pageUrl", pageUrl);
  url.searchParams.append("size", size.toString());

  return url.href;
};


favicon("https://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Additionaly add `loading="lazy"` attribute for you image, to prevent hundreds request.